# When using CKEditor in inline mode, when can be be sure that the editor is fully ready?

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor with `CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true`.

I then call `inlineAll()` to inline all `contenteditable`s.

Immediately, after, I am getting data out of the editor:

```
CKEDITOR.inlineAll();
var editor = ... //get the editor instance
console.log(editor.getData());
```

The problem is that CKEDITOR changes the markup, and the one I get using `getData()` is before the change.

This is what the content markup looks like:

```
<p>test<a href="test.com">aaa</a>test test<a href="test.com">bbb</a>test</p>
<p>test asdf</p>
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">link</a>
<p>test</p>
<a href="http://google.com">link</a>
<p>test</p>
```

CKEDITOR modifies the markup so that the `<a>`s are in their own paragraphs:

```
<p>test<a href="test.com">aaa</a>test test<a href="test.com">bbb</a>test</p>
<p>test asdf</p>
<p><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">link</a></p>
<p>test</p>
<p><a href="http://google.com">link</a></p>
<p>test</p>
```

The problem is that the markup I receive using `getData()` is the one before the modification.

What can I do to ensure that CKEditor is ready and the markup from `getData()` is the most up to date markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [`editor.status`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-property-status) property and [`editor#instanceReady`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-instanceReady) event. When the event is fired, the status is changed to `'ready'`. Before that editor may return cached editable element's `innerHTML` instead of processed data.

So if you want to be sure that you get real data, then you need to check status and wait for instance to be ready if it isn't yet.